# What are typical functions in object oriented programming?

Tags: programming-languages

I Could not find answer anywhere on the internet. 
can someone  please  explain with example.

Comment: Well, if you're using Java, then technically there are no functions, only _methods_.  Speaking of which, you should tell us which programming language you are actually using.

Comment: i am using c++....the question i was given was what are typical functions and iterator methods in OOP

Answer (score 2):

Functions are normally referred to procedural programming. In OOP, you have methods which are actually functions in nature, work the same as functions but they always work in relation to some object. You cannot declare a method/function without creating a class for it, similarly you need to always call functions using its object. So, the approach of making functions and just calling them to work doesn't work the same way in OOP. You have to associate them with a class here and usually with a constructor for that class too.

Let me show you that with an example. 
Suppose we are writing code in C, which is a procedural language, a function looks like this:

```
int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Now for java, the method in OOP looks like this,

```
class NumberAdder{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    NumberAdder(int num1, int num2){
        this.num1=num1;
        this.num2=num2;
    }
    public int getSum(){
        return num1+num2;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering the question , but the question was given to me and today it was made more specific -"what are typical functions and iterator methods in oop(c++)  ?".

Comment: +One. Technically this is true, but the question needs to be answered from a C++ perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the application and how everything is organized. In OOP, the word "methods" is actually preferred to distinguish from "functions" which are not part of an object. Look at the documentation for any library and you should find some examples.

Unity is a game engine and should make sense intuitively. `Collider` has methods for finding nearest points and detecting collisions. `ParticleSystem` has a method for emitting particles. `Camera` has a method for rendering. etc.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html